# How does ADO.NET Connection Pooling work with .ASMX Web Services?

Tags: c#, connection, asmx, pooling

I've created an old-style .ASMX web service and would like to know how the built-in ADO.NET connection pooling works with it.

The web service is not using a singleton pattern, so it is instantiated anew with every request.  My question is will connections be removed from the pool after each service request, or are they kept in the pool across requests?  My service is called very frequently but I don't want to be doing setup and teardown of connections every time, if it can be avoided.

I have read that the pool is maintained for the AppDomain, but I'm not sure if each request generates a new AppDomain or not.

I am also curious if it would be beneficial to set Min Pool Size (to a small number other than 0) in this case.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No each request does not generate a new app domain.  All the requests for that web site/application are in the same application domain, and so share the connection pool. Once the asmx request is finished with the connection, it returns it to the pool and the next request in line grabs it (assuming there isn't another connection in the pool readily available).

One point of clarification.  You can have two different web applications which point to the same code, and are in different app domains.  The two applications don't share anything (think about launching the same application twice).

> I am also curious if it would be
>   beneficial to set Min Pool Size (to a
>   small number other than 0) in this
>   case.

So it can be beneficial depending on the application.  Creating connections takes time, so having some ready allows you to forgo that.  If you have request that say uses one connection, that might be fine to make a person wait for (it all depends on fast you want the application to respond).  This can really come into play when you need to say 3 or 4 different ones (you get the point) open for one request.  So why would you need multiple connections?  What about one for accessing data and a separate thread for logging to the database (logging to the database vs a file is a totally different conversation)? Now you need two.  There are multiple scenarios where this can come into play.  Depending on your database server holding an open connection can be pretty cheap, so setting it to a small number can be a huge bang for your buck.  (For the record I've seen scenarios where connecting to a database took several seconds, like 3-5, so in that case holding an open connection for a user was beneficial.)

**This is for Max Pool Size**
No it's not beneficial, because all requests to that service use the same pool (assuming the connections are using the same connection string, and aren't hitting different servers.  Those have separate connection pools).  Having no available connections, is a really fast and surefire way of crushing the performance of your service.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I suspected but wanted some verification.

Comment: I thought setting Min Pool Size meant that there would always be x number of connections available, and not destroyed after some amount of idle time.